# How to customize gridlines in a polar chart so that limit values don't show?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following example, I am producing a polar chart for a variable that ranges from 1 to 10.

Suppose I need to set limit values from -1 to 11 (to control the way the chart is shown and create enough space for outer labels).

How do I adjust the code so I only show gridlines for the breaks at 0, 5 and 10 and not for the limit value of 11?

Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame( seq(1, 10), 
                  seq(1, 10))
names(df) <- c("a", "b")

ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=a, y=b), stat="identity", alpha=0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1, 11), breaks =c(0,5,10))+
  theme( panel.grid =element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y= element_line(color="red", size=2))+
  coord_polar()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way in ggplot2 to do this. However, we can work our way around this by defining a custom `Coord` class. You can find a quick and dirty version of this below. The only change (aside from prefixing ggplot2 internal functions with `ggplot2:::`) is in the assignment of the `rfine` variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

custom_coord <- ggproto(
  NULL, coord_polar(),
  render_bg = function(self, panel_params, theme) {
    panel_params <- ggplot2:::rename_data(self, panel_params)
    
    theta <- if (length(panel_params$theta.major) > 0)
      ggplot2:::theta_rescale(self, panel_params$theta.major, panel_params)
    thetamin <- if (length(panel_params$theta.minor) > 0)
      ggplot2:::theta_rescale(self, panel_params$theta.minor, panel_params)
    thetafine <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100)
    
    # Here is the bit that I changed, I dropped the automatic 0.45 for outer ring
    rfine <- c(ggplot2:::r_rescale(self, 
                                   panel_params$r.major, 
                                   panel_params$r.range))
    
    majortheta <- paste("panel.grid.major.", self$theta, sep = "")
    minortheta <- paste("panel.grid.minor.", self$theta, sep = "")
    majorr     <- paste("panel.grid.major.", self$r,     sep = "")
    
    ggplot2:::ggname("grill", grobTree(
      element_render(theme, "panel.background"),
      if (length(theta) > 0) element_render(
        theme, majortheta, name = "angle",
        x = c(rbind(0, 0.45 * sin(theta))) + 0.5,
        y = c(rbind(0, 0.45 * cos(theta))) + 0.5,
        id.lengths = rep(2, length(theta)),
        default.units = "native"
      ),
      if (length(thetamin) > 0) element_render(
        theme, minortheta, name = "angle",
        x = c(rbind(0, 0.45 * sin(thetamin))) + 0.5,
        y = c(rbind(0, 0.45 * cos(thetamin))) + 0.5,
        id.lengths = rep(2, length(thetamin)),
        default.units = "native"
      ),
      
      element_render(
        theme, majorr, name = "radius",
        x = rep(rfine, each = length(thetafine)) * sin(thetafine) + 0.5,
        y = rep(rfine, each = length(thetafine)) * cos(thetafine) + 0.5,
        id.lengths = rep(length(thetafine), length(rfine)),
        default.units = "native"
      )
    ))
  }
)
```

Note that the quick and dirty bit is that the above is *just* the class. If you'd want to do this better, you'd need a constructor function too. Once we have our custom coord, we can use it as follows:

```
df <- data.frame( seq(1, 10), 
                  seq(1, 10))
names(df) <- c("a", "b")

ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=a, y=b), stat="identity", alpha=0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1, 11), breaks =c(0,5,10),
                     minor_breaks = c(0, 5, 10))+
  theme( panel.grid =element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.y= element_line(color="red", size=2))+
  custom_coord
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

EDIT: way less complicated:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame( seq(1, 10), 
                  seq(1, 10))
names(df) <- c("a", "b")

ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=a, y=b), stat="identity", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, 5, 10), colour = "red", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1, 11), breaks =c(0,5,10))+
  theme( panel.grid =element_blank())+
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Too bad if there's no easy way to implement this in ggplot. I tried using minor_breaks in scale_y_continuous but these didn't show. An alternative that I know of is to use geom_segment to draw a segment for each observation, but that doesn't produce a perfect circle.

Comment: Yeah I've probably been overthinking this, your segment approach is much easier but uses the wrong geom. `geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, 5, 10), colour = "red", size = 2)` seems to do a very similar thing to what I did, in a much simpler way.

Comment: Exactly... just thought of a very similar solution using geom_segment! Thanks for your solution, which is even more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a solution through scale_y_continuous, I think this might be the easiest way:

```
df22 <- data.frame( seq(1, 10), 
                  seq(1, 10))

names(df22) <- c("a", "b")

ggplot(df22) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(a), y=b), stat="identity", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=0, xend=11, yend=0), color="red", size=2)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=5, xend=11, yend=5), color="red", size=2)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, y=10, xend=11, yend=10), color="red", size=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1, 11))+
  theme( panel.grid =element_blank())+
  coord_polar()
```